# Why the capability 'activate_plugins' is needed to allow a role to see all posts/pages/comments?

Tags: comments, user-roles, capabilities

Example:

I create a **new role** and assign to it the capabilities `moderate_comments` and `edit_posts` (this one is needed to enable the comments moderation cap.).
This new role **can't see all the comments** published on the website. For example, the website has 20 comments but, when the user with the new role open the Comments panel in the wp-admin, the comments list is **empty**. The counter notify that there are 20 comments, but they are not listed. 
However, I found that the capability `activate_plugins` gives to the new role the possibility to see **all** the comments. In other words, when the new role has the cap. `activate_plugins` all the 20 comments are listed in the wp-admin comments moderation page. The same happens with posts and pages.

Why this happens? And, is there a way to see all the comments, the posts and the pages from the new role **without** enabling the superflous cap. `activate_plugins`?
Thank you all.

Comment: this sounds like a problem with the plugins you use. the `activate_plugins`capability should not have any impact on the comments

Comment: In fact this is so strange...

Comment: Ok, fantastic... found the plugin that is causing all my wordpress-related problems.